# How can I connect my static page (Dapp) to my ipfs node?

Tags: ipfs

The very naive way I'm going about it is:

`const node = new Ipfs({ host: "xxx.ip.address.xxx"});`

When I save an image from the static page, it does give me an ipfs hash back and save it to the local browser cache,  but when I run on my ipfs node:

`ipfs dht findpeer QmVLRBHgCvFhPbxenyPpM1UnoLMY9kPhB6vyU2JmenaLYv`

My node can't find the file.

PS: I'm running the IPFS node on Digital Ocean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the IPFS host to `0.0.0.0`

```
ipfs config Addresses.API /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/5001
ipfs config Addresses.Gateway /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/9001
```

You may also need to set CORS:

```
ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin '["*"]'
```

Restart IPFS daemon.